# Add array to another array as object

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to add array as object to another array..
So thats why I am doint this :

```
-(void)compute:(NSMutableArray *)ary completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
   int id=0;
   NSLog(@"Array is%@",ary);
   NSArray *temp;
   for(int i=0;i<[ary count];i++){
       temp=[ary objectAtIndex:i];
       id=[[temp objectAtIndex:4] integerValue];
       NSLog(@"temp is%@ %d",temp,id);
      // [MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray addobject:temp];
   }
   NSLog(@"%@",MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray);
}
```

But in Log I am getting null in MYAppDelegate.searchResultArray. In log I got value of temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
-(void)compute:(NSMutableArray *)ary completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
 int id=0;
 NSLog(@"Array is%@",ary);
 NSMutableArray *temp;
 for(int i=0;i<[ary count];i++){
temp=[ary objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"string%@",[temp objectAtIndex:8]);
if(id==[[temp objectAtIndex:4] integerValue]){
    NSLog(@"inside");
    NSMutableArray *temp1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    temp1=[MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
    NSLog(@"temp1%@",temp1);
    NSString *tempStr=[[temp1 objectAtIndex:8] stringByAppendingString:[temp objectAtIndex:8]];
    NSLog(@"%@",tempStr);
    [temp1 replaceObjectAtIndex:8 withObject:tempStr];
    [MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i-1 withObject:temp1];
}
else{
id=[[temp objectAtIndex:4] integerValue];
NSLog(@"temp is%@ %d",temp,id);
[MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray addObject:temp];
}
}
NSLog(@"%@",MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray);
}
```